# React Native Android app crashes in production

Tags: android, react-native, crash

React Native Android Application is crashing in release mode. I am not able to discover the issue or a fix
here are the dependencies used

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^7.1.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.9.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^12.9.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^12.9.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^2.15.2",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "radio-buttons-react-native": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.20.5",
    "react-native": "0.67.3",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "^3.2.4",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.36.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.7.3",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.4",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-multiple-select": "^0.5.6",
    "react-native-navigation-bar-color": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "6.6.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-story": "^0.1.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-textarea": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-url-preview": "^1.1.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.16.0",
    "react-native-windows": "0.41.0-rc.1",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-use-websocket": "^2.7.1",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.2.0",
    "zego-express-engine-reactnative": "^0.17.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.0",
    "@bam.tech/react-native-make": "^3.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.25.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In release mode you still can check the logs. you can use android logcats to view the all logs of mobile. filter the logs so to find easier the problem and look fo "Caused by" keyword in logs.